# Problems registering Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have the following problem. When registering a free Google Cloud account, I get the error "We weren't able to establish your payments profile. To finish setting up your free trial, get help from our Support team." I click on the "Go to support" button. Then I go to the "GCP Billing support" section and click on the "Get GCP Billing Support" button. Then I get the following message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJKMt.png)

What should I do? What is the problem...?

Comment: Start by contacting your credit card and ask them why they declined the transaction.

Comment: you are not an administrator with billing rights as stated, do you have (over) read the error?